# How to get server IP-address in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

In my tornado-based application I need to store the server's IP-address (e.g. the address that was used by the user to connect to the server) in session. How to determine this IP-address in Tornado? I'm using Tornado 2.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind throwing in some dependencies, you can do this from a [request handler](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler):

```
import socket
import urlparse    

hostname = urlparse.urlparse("%s://%s"
    % (self.request.protocol, self.request.host)).hostname

ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

An important thing to note here is that [`self.request.host`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.host) can include a port number. That's why it is preferred to parse it using `urlparse`.

Comment: socket.gethostbyname will hold up the Tornado event loop while the DNS query completes.  In modern Tornado please use tornado.netutil.Resolver instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can dig into the `HttpServerRequest` object as [documented here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest).

You are using a pretty old version of Tornado, though.